# Spotify Linux-preview download error

Tags: spotify

I'm trying to download the Spotify Linux preview onto to computer, which is running Ubuntu 14.04.

I've followed the instructions, inputting the following code:

`sudo apt-add-repository -y "deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free" &&
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com -recv-keys 94558F59 &&
sudo apt-get updates -qq &&
sudo apt-get spotify-client`

However, having done that, I recieved the following error message:
`spotify-client: Depends: libnspr4-0d but it is not installable
            Recommends: libavcodec53 but it is not installable or
                        libavcodec52 but it is not installable or
                        libavcodec-extra-53 but it is not installable or
                        libavcodec-extra-52 but it is not installable
            Recommends: libavcodec53 but it is not installable or
                        libavcodec52 but it is not installable or
                        libavcodec-extra-53 but it is not installable or
                        libavcodec-extra-52 but it is not installable`

If this question has been asked before, could anyone lead me to the answer? Otherwise, can someone help me? I've tried numerous other things, but none of them seem to work...

Comment: "Updates"is not a valid command in "sudo apt-get updates" maybe that's your issue. Also "sudo apt-get spotify-client" won't install spotify without the "install"order.